# Element not becoming hidden on page load in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS.
The following JS code is not working when the page loads.

```
function alert10() {

  var today = new Date().getMinutes();
  if (today > 10) {

    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('timer10').style.display = 'none';
    };

  }
}
```

I'm calling alert10() as follows :

```
<header onload="alert10()">
```

The following is the element I'm trying to hide :

```
<h5 id="timer10"  style=" position:absolute;top: 1px;left: 151px;"></h5>
```

Comment: Do you _call_ `alert10`?

Comment: yes, I'm adding it to the header.

Comment: please share your all html

Comment: Could you verify that the element with the ID `timer10` actually exists in the DOM? And I'm pretty sure that the event listener you've added wouldn't work once that method has been called.

Comment: Since you using var and not const/let, today is not defined before next line running - https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-what-is-hoisting-in-javascript-a63c1b2267a1

Comment: Added more details about the element to be hidden

Comment: Is this JS Code written in a separate file and included in your html?

Comment: No, it's in the same file

Comment: why not you just use `window.onload` instead of listening load event of header and then listen to window load event. it does not makes sense to me

Comment: I'm trying many things at the same time, but nothing is working. If you have an answer , please add.

Comment: when you are adding load event to element the event bubbles up so it means all of element listens to the event so when you are adding load event listener to header body and html is also listening to that event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following using [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h5 id="timer10" style=" position:absolute;top: 1px;left: 151px;">Something</h5>
  <script>
    window.onload = () => {
      var today = new Date().getMinutes();
      if (today > 10) {
        document.getElementById('timer10').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        alert('minutes is less than 10')
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the header onload function executes, the window onload has probably fired already. If you take the window listener out of the function, the timer is hidden as intended (provided 10 minutes are past since the last hour started). It works as well if you use e.g. a click listener or any other subsequent trigger.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('timer11').style.display = 'none';
};

function alert10() {
  var today = new Date().getMinutes();
  if (today > 10) {
      document.getElementById('timer10').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    console.log("10 minutes haven't past since last hour started")
  }
}
```

I've added a second timer to show both

```html
<header onload="alert10()" onclick="alert10()">
  <h5 id="timer10"  style=" position:absolute;top: 1px;left: 151px;">timer10</h5>
  <h5 id="timer11"  style=" position:absolute;top: 1px;left: 251px;">timer11</h5>
</header>
```

and a bit of css to make the clickable area apparent

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
```